# How to get 'self' from Lua event handler function?

Tags: lua, add-on, world-of-warcraft

```
local tbl = {a = 1}

-- Passed and executed function
function tbl:handleFunc(x, y)
    print(self.a + x + y)
end

-- I know the above code is syntax sugar.
-- tbl["handleFunc"] = function(self, x, y)
--     print(self.a + x + y)
-- end

-- Register event handlers that I can't control the call
Frame:SetScript("OnClick", tbl.handleFunc)

-- Probably called when an event occurs.
tbl.handleFunc(2, 3)

-- Then it will be like this.
tbl.handleFunc(2, 3, nil)

-- So I wrote a function like this
function tbl.handleFunc(x, y)
    local self = tbl  -- This variable is too cumbersome
    -- And this way, every time I call a function, I need to check whether the function definition is a dot (.) Or colon (:)

end
```

When calling a function, In situations where you can't pass *self*, Is there a way to use *self*?

If not, how should I design?

---

[Solved] I used a translator but I want to be polite. Thank you for the nice answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to avoid unnecessary work is to write a function that will wrap the function for you before you register it as a handler:

```lua
local tbl = {a = 1}

function tbl:handleFunc(x, y)
    print(self.a + x + y)
end

function wrap_with(obj, func)
    return function(...)
        return func(obj, ...)
    end
end

Frame:SetScript("OnClick", wrap_with(tbl, tbl.handleFunc))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use an anonymous function that calls the actual function

```
Frame:SetScript("OnClick", function(x,y) tbl:handleFunc(x, y) end)
```